# Flatmap-stream had a malicious commit and hence was removed. Now I cannot run my website due to it being a dependency. Any tips on what I should do?

Tags: node.js, compiler-errors

So I had my project parked for the holiday season but today I tried running it locally and got a lovely message from windows defender about a specific file from the flatmap-stream node module being malicious. I read up a bit about it and from what I gather there has been a malicious commit which forced the module to be removed entirely. The problem is that I have a dependency to this module and now cannot run my website locally. Also a problem is that I am unaware which module is dependent on it as I'm not very literate in the scene yet.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMvXx.png) is the error I get when I try to run the website without the specific module present.

Can anyone please shed some light which module is annoyed about this?
Or maybe perhaps how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `npm uninstall flatmap-stream` will take out the dependency. Be sure that you do not include it anymore in your file, for example `import Flat from "flatmap-stream";`

If you do want to use it, then uninstall like I said and reinstall.

Comment: That worked, thanks!
However I'll just leave a comment if anyone else looks into this - I found another method as well. Just because I'm fearful that something in the site might actually be using it I tried to just delete the whole node_modules folder and replace all of my module versions in package.json to "*" so that the latest versions would be downloaded. Surely enough that also worked and the flatmap-stream module is no longer present within the files. I'm assuming the respective devs removed the dependency after this whole malicious code story.